# App that enables the missing charging light and notification light in Samsung S10, S10 Plus and S10e

Tags: applications, notification-led

I moved from Samsung Galaxy S6 to Samsung Galaxy S10e, and found out that there's a fundamental functionality missing:

There are no indicator lights (AKA [LED light](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/85184)) for different cellphone states.

This means:

1. No indication lights for new notifications (in Samsung Galaxy S6, it's e.g. blue light for messages, white light for Whatsapp messages, and so on).
2. No indication lights for charging state (in Samsung Galaxy S6, red light is for charging or battery below 15%, green light is for full charge).

I'm looking for an app that compensates this unfortunate lack, with one important requirement:
It should work even when "Always on Display" functionality is off - as it was on Samsung Galaxy S6.

Is there an app that enables this?

Comment: Please note that questions for app recommendations are off-topic here

Comment: I'm surprised. I checked on meta before posting, and saw that several answers (e.g., [1](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31/is-what-is-an-app-that-does-x-y-and-z-a-valid-question/), [2](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-what-apps-should-i-get-questions-appropriate)) say it's allowed if asked in a specific way.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) and [Where to ask for app recommendations?](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575). PS: Your #2 explicitly states "no" ;) **Answers** can recomment apps as solutions, but explicitly asking for apps is off-topic.

Comment: I see. Well, if you can kindly move my post to Software Recommendations it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

After trying about 10 different apps, I found (only) a single app that answers these requirements:

**LED Me know**

*I'm by no way affiliated with this app.*

Here's how to achieve these 2 requirements:

*Do yourself a favor and don't be afraid of this extensive writeup. If you're like me, absolutely craving for these basic functionalities, it's completely worth the effort!*

**Setup**

First, ***Always on Display*** *must* be turned on.

Now, to get rid of this distracting clock and notification icons:

1. Go to "hamburger" menu > "Setup", and swipe the "Hide AOD" slider to an enabled state.
2. Go to Settings > Lock screen > clock style > Always On Display > select the "edge" option (the one where the clock and date appear on the edge of the screen).

The combination of these two will actually remove all content from the Always on Display screen.

**Charging light**

Under the app's "hamburger" menu, there are 3 relevant options:

1. Charging Style
2. Fully Charged Style
3. Low Battery Style

Under each one of them:

1. Swipe the "Charging Enabled" slider to an enabled state.
2. Under "Charging Color", pick the colors you're used to from your previous Samsung device.
3. Under "Charging Style", pick circle.
4. Under "Interval", set "Show For **60** seconds", and "Hide for **0** Seconds" (for some reason, you can't actually enter a 0, so that erase the default value (which is 1 seconds)).
5. Recommended: under "Customize", set width to 120, height to 120, Left position to 915, and top position to 10. This would make the circle. This would actually position the indicator light as a "halo" around the front camera.

**Notification light**

1. Under the app's "hamburger" menu, go to Baseline Style menu.
   Then:
   a. Swipe the "LED Enabled" slider to an enabled state.
   b. Set "Stop after # minutes" to 0.
   c. Recommended: Follow step 5 above in a similar way to set the indicator light shape and position.
2. Under the app's "hamburger" menu, go to Customize Apps menu, and only choose whichever apps you'd like to enable. You can customize a different color for every app.
   Also, mark the "Show System Apps" option to display system apps like Calls and Messages - you probably want lights for them as well.